# Return values based on column separated by comma and two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table below:

[image: My Table]

I want to add a column (Evaluation) that returns one of the elements in the cars columns (separated by comma). The element to return will be based on the Ferrari and Toyota columns. The Evaluation column returns the element that the individual does not have. So take the first row, for example, John has one Ferrari and no Toyota. Since John has no Toyota, the evaluation column returns Toyota.

[image: Result]

I would prefer to have the decision made using the cars column, separating the text by comma and looking up the text against the values under Ferrari and Toyota

Comment: Anybody with answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['John'] * 2 + ['Peter'] * 2 + ['Sam'] * 2,
                   'Cars':['Ferrari, Toyota','Ferrari','Ferrari, Toyota','Ferrari',
                           'Ferrari, Toyota','Ferrari, Toyota'],
                   'Ferrari': [1,1,0,0,1,1], 
                   'Toyota': [0,1,1,0,1,0]})

df['Evaluation1'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].ne(1).dot(df.columns[2:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)
   Names             Cars  Ferrari  Toyota      Evaluation1
0   John  Ferrari, Toyota        1       0           Toyota
1   John          Ferrari        1       1                 
2  Peter  Ferrari, Toyota        0       1          Ferrari
3  Peter          Ferrari        0       0  Ferrari, Toyota
4    Sam  Ferrari, Toyota        1       1                 
5    Sam  Ferrari, Toyota        1       0           Toyota
```

**Details**:

First seelct all columns without first 2 by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and create boolean mask - compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (`!=`):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 2:].ne(1))
   Ferrari  Toyota
0    False    True
1    False   False
2     True   False
3     True    True
4    False   False
5    False    True
```

Then use matrix multiplication by [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names with separator:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 2:].ne(1).dot(df.columns[2:] + ', '))
0             Toyota, 
1                     
2            Ferrari, 
3    Ferrari, Toyota, 
4                     
5             Toyota, 
dtype: object
```

And remove last separator by [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 2:].ne(1).dot(df.columns[2:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', '))
0             Toyota
1                   
2            Ferrari
3    Ferrari, Toyota
4                   
5             Toyota
dtype: object
```

If not possible select by position because positions should be changed of columns without `0,1` is possible use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove unecessary columns:

```
df1 = df.drop(['Names','Ferrari'], axis=1).ne(1)
df['Evaluation2'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,0,1,1], 'b': [0,1,0,1]})
```

Creates the following DataFrame:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
```

You can add a new column with a list of column names equal to zero with:

```
df['evaluated'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[x == 0]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b evaluated
0  0  0       a,b
1  0  1         a
2  1  0         b
3  1  1
```